# Word for cold sensetive person

Tags: word-usage

Is there any formal and informal word for person too sensetive to cold, like she/he easily starting shaking with it if goes outside

Comment: I immediately thought of [nesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesh), but it's probably too much of a dialect word for your purposes.

Comment: @KateBunting I think it is widely used though so probably is the best option at least in BrE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no one English word that says all that. You have to use a short phrase,   such as:

Cold-sensitive

Easily chilled

Susceptible to shivering

Frosbite-prone

By the way, be aware that "frigid" has a special connotation as an adjective for a female person, and in that sense has nothing to do with temperature.